# Urllib downloads file as requested everywhere except on my laptop

Tags: python, download, urllib

I have a Python script that downloads a GRIB file (weather forecast data) from the NOAA website based on a date, time, and hours to forecast ahead.  Basically the Python pieces together a big URL request and posts it over to the NOAA website.  This works great on the computers at school and it worked great for some previous stack-overflowers that assisted me with the code.  However, the same exact script fails 9 out of 10 times using Python on my computer, even though when I make Python print out the URL and I copy it into Firefox, it works fine every time. Changing the library to urllib2 doesn't change anything.

So I can say the following:  somehow urllib is not able to get the data I want if I am using my computer but the script works fine everywhere else.  Urllib can scrape HTML off of other websites on my computer with no problem but somehow this particular download is giving it trouble.

I am running Ubuntu precise and using Python 2.7.3 on a laptop with a wireless connection when I try to run the script at home.  I have tested it on an a wired computer with ubuntu precise and it works every time (also tested on fedora, also works there).

Please tell me some diagnostics I can do to figure out why urllib and my computer aren't playing nice.  And thank you; this problem is standing in the way of the next generation of high altitude balloon launches.

Heres what it tells me 90% of the time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dantayaga/bovine_aerospace/dev/grib_get.py", line 67, in <module>
webf=urllib.urlopen(griburl, data='POST')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 88, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 209, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Here is the code I am using (credit to samy.vilar et al for improved pythonicity).  Note that you have to input today's date and a forecast time of 00, 06, 12 or 18 (GMT) otherwise you may get a 404 not found. Keep forecast hours the same.

## Get GRIB files

```
import urllib
#import os

#os.environ['http_proxy']='' #Doesn't seem to help!

forecast_time='06' #What time the forecast is (00, 06, 12, 18)
forecast_hours='12' #How many hours ahead to forecast (2 or 3 digits)
forecast_date='20120720' #What date the forecast is for yyyymmdd

top_lat=90 #Top of bounding box (North)
bottom_lat=-90 #Bottom of bounding box (South)
left_lon=-90 #Left of bounding box (West)
right_lon=90 #Right of bounding box (East)

griburl='http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl?'
griburl=griburl+'file=gfs.t'+str(forecast_time)+'z.mastergrb2f'
griburl=griburl+forecast_hours

#Select atmospheric levels

griburl=griburl+'&lev_1000_mb=on'  #1000 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_975_mb=on'   #975 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_950_mb=on'   #950 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_925_mb=on'   #925 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_900_mb=on'   #900 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_850_mb=on'   #850 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_800_mb=on'   #800 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_750_mb=on'   #750 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_700_mb=on'   #700 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_650_mb=on'   #650 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_600_mb=on'   #600 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_550_mb=on'   #550 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_500_mb=on'   #500 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_450_mb=on'   #450 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_400_mb=on'   #400 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_350_mb=on'   #350 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_300_mb=on'   #300 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_250_mb=on'   #250 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_200_mb=on'   #200 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_150_mb=on'   #150 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_100_mb=on'   #100 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_70_mb=on'    #70 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_30_mb=on'    #30 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_20_mb=on'    #20 mb level
griburl=griburl+'&lev_10_mb=on'    #10 mb level

#Select variables

griburl=griburl+'&var_HGT=on'  #Height (geopotential m)
griburl=griburl+'&var_RH=on'  #Relative humidity (%)
griburl=griburl+'&var_TMP=on' #Temperature (K)
griburl=griburl+'&var_UGRD=on' #East-West component of wind (m/s)
griburl=griburl+'&var_VGRD=on' #North-South component of wind (m/s)
griburl=griburl+'&var_VVEL=on' #Vertical Windspeed (Pa/s)

#Select bounding box

griburl=griburl+'leftlon='+str(left_lon)
griburl=griburl+'rightlon='+str(right_lon)
griburl=griburl+'toplat='+str(top_lat)
griburl=griburl+'bottomlat='+str(bottom_lat)

#Select date and time

griburl=griburl+'&dir=%2Fgfs.'+forecast_date+forecast_time+'%2Fmaster'
print(griburl)
print('Downloading GRIB file for date '+forecast_date+' time ' +forecast_time + ', forecasting '+forecast_hours+' hours ahead...')
webf=urllib.urlopen(griburl, data='POST')
print("Download complete.  Saving...")
local_filename=forecast_date+'_'+forecast_time+'_'+forecast_hours+'.grib'
localf=open(local_filename, 'wb')
localf.write(webf.read())
print('Requested grib data written to file '+local_filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This exception indicates that your laptop is not able to resolve the host name into an IP address. The DNS lookup is handled by the socket library, and this will be independent of whether you use `urllib` or `urllib2` (or anything else for that matter).

You need to look at your network set up, in particular your DNS server. It could be that Firefox is configured to use a proxy, in which case it is delegating the DNS lookup to the proxy.

It's odd that you don't have problems with other sites; I can't explain why HTML scraping using `urllib` works for other sites (perhaps proxy is enabled for these scripts?), but the exception that you're experiencing is definitely related to DNS.

If you do find that Firefox is using a proxy, try setting your script up to use the same proxy. A simple way is to invoke your Python script like this:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy:1234 python grib_get.py
```

Alternatively, for diagnostic purposes, you could temporarily hard code the ip address of the remote server into your URLs, i.e.

```
griburl='http://140.90.33.62/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl?'
```

Comment: Firefox is set to "use system proxy settings" and:                   gconftool-2 -g /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy returns "False"    /system/http_proxy/host is an empty string and /system/http_proxy/port is 8080.  This should mean I am **not** using a proxy in Firefox or anywhere else...am I correct?  Any other tests I should try?

Comment: Is it possible that this is not my problem, but something going on at NOAA?  A friend of mine had trouble resolving the URl by pasting into Firefox, and I recently just got on the website using the IP address you posted, then got timed out 5 minutes later.  Maybe some combination of lag on my computer plus really bad latency on their end?  If so is there any solution besides pinging them X number of times until the file finally downloads?  Also note [this balloon model](http://weather.uwyo.edu/polar/balloon_traj.html) sometimes times out, and they use the same data set.

Comment: @glossarch: It is not impossible that it is a problem with the remote server, however, your tests show that as unlikely - you get 100% success using other connections and computers etc. Timeout is another issue, but from the Python exception it is clearly a dns resolution issue. What name server are you using? What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: i will have a look at resolv.conf when I get home.  I was able to get things to work last night by having it attempt the download 10 times, waiting a second between attempts.  Usually after the second or third time I would get the file (though once not after 9 tries).  However since my computer is at least part of the problem as you said, I'd like something more stable/reliable...and so I'll have a look at DNS.  Plus I don't want to keep hammering NOAA if (part) of the problem's on my end.

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf contains this:                                      `nameserver 127.0.0.1` and nothing else.  Is this the issue at hand?

Comment: OK, fixed it.  You were right, it was a nameserver issue.  I found a way to cat a couple of nameservers into resolv.conf ( google and opendns respectively) my code works like a charm.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @glassarch - glad you have it sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether it a memory problem, running low on memory so it's being paged out to disk, slowing it down too much.

Anyway, you're printing "Download complete.  Saving..." before you've actually downloaded anything!

Try this instead:

```
print('Downloading GRIB file for date '+forecast_date+' time ' +forecast_time + ', forecasting '+forecast_hours+' hours ahead...')
local_filename=forecast_date+'_'+forecast_time+'_'+forecast_hours+'.grib'
webf=urllib.urlopen(griburl, data='POST')
localf=open(local_filename, 'wb')
BLOCK_SIZE = 4096
while True:
    block = webf.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    if not block:
        break
    localf.write(block)
localf.close()
webf.close()
print("Download complete.  Saving...")
```

Comment: Ah, well.  As you can see, I'm still learning.  I was elated when your loop seemed to solve the problem at first.  I got 4 consecutive downloads but then it started failing again with the same error code.  I tried setting BLOCK_SIZE to 2048 and that did not bring it back.  It may be a coincidence that it worked those first few times.

Comment: Could you download a few atmospheric levels at a time instead of all of them together?

Comment: Yeah, certainly could.  My model won't always ascend to the top of the layers anyway, so if it is purely a data transfer problem I may try and reduce my overhead.  However I can't predict how high up I need to go until I run the model, so it slows down my model runs if I have to stop and request more data during the calculations.

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you still download it all, just in chunks instead.